# Woocommerce - hide an element if logged in, show element if logged out

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

i've found the following code to make an element change to display:block; if a user is logged in

```
.logged-in .price{
 display: none;
 }
```

and also

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '<style>p.price {display:none;}</style>';
} else {
echo '<style>p.price {display:block;}</style>';
}
?>
```

but neither seems to work properly. it will hide the element, but if i log out, the element is still hidden. does anyone have an answer? thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

The body tag will have a `logged-in` class when the user is logged in. So using the following will work.

```css
body.logged-in .price {
    display: none !important;
}
```

If you want to remove the `!important` attribute then you would need to target more specifically which `.price` element you wish to remove due to Woocommerce being very specific with it's css selectors.

Also to note, you can add a `:not()` modified to the body selector if you wish to do the reverse, i.e...

```css
body:not(.logged-in) .price {
   // do something...
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, i really appreciate ite.

the problem is (i'm not sure if this is a chrome thing, i get the same problem in internet explorer as well as chrome) - i put the two css parts in as stated in your answer, but again, when i log out and refresh the product page - it is still displaying as if i'm logged in?

so if the rule is set as display:block for logged in, and display:none for logged out, it will still show as display:block when i log out

Answer (score 1):

Try following code that worked fine for me.

```php
function example_function() {
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo '<style>p.price { display: none; }</style>';
  }
}
add_action('init', 'example_function');
```

Comment: thanks again - although unfortunately the same problem. think it could be a browser issue? i tried in incognito as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. The addition I forgot to mention was to have the element to stay hidden until clicked again - which is a localStorage thing.

Final code is below:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="tradePriceToggle"> Hide Trade Price

<script>
   $(function() {
   var status = localStorage.getItem('chkStatus');
     if(status == 'true'){
     $("span.price").css("display", "none");
     $(".tradePriceToggle").attr('checked', true)
   }
   else {
        $("span.price").css("display", "block");
        $(".tradePriceToggle").attr('checked', false)
  }
  $(".tradePriceToggle").click(function() {
if (this.checked) {
  $("span.price").hide();
}
else {
  $("span.price").show();
}
localStorage.setItem("chkStatus", this.checked);
});
});
</script>
```